# How to add "always on top" button to window decoration in eOS?

Tags: window-manager, elementary-os

Using the Tweaks tool, it's possible to change the buttons layout and also add a minimize button.

However, how could we add a button for toggling "always on top"?

There's a "custom layout" option in Tweaks, where you can write the buttons names and order them. Maybe there's a name for the always on top button? I've tried "top" and "alwaysontop" without success.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only supported values in Mutter are "menu" "minimize" "maximize" "spacer" and "close". It doesn't appear to be possible to add a button for always on top.

Comment: Is it possible to do without a button? I.e., is there any way to get a window to be always on top?

Comment: @James  Yes, right click and select "Always on top"